# Extraer info del array y dentro hay otro array

Tags: array, reactjs

Estoy recorriendo un array de objetos con el método .map pero necesito mostrar el array de objetos dentro del mismo "producto" adicionalmente el array de "aplicaciones"... ya que el "producto" tiene dichas aplicaciones, he recorrido el array con .map.. todo bien, pero las aplicaciones seria genial que estén dentro de un ul>li.. dentro de la misma tarjeta del producto..

```js
  const aplicaciones = productos.length > 0 && productos.map((serie) => {
    console.log('productosLENGHT', productos.length)
    return (
      <div style={{ border: '1px solid blue' }}>
        <h1>{serie.nombre} </h1>
        {serie.marca.length > 0 && serie.marca.map((season) => (
          <>
            <p>{season.nombreMarca}</p>
            <p>{season.precioVenta}</p>
          </>
        ))}
        {serie.aplicacion.length > 0 && serie.aplicacion.map((season) => (
          <ul>
            <li>{season}</li>
          </ul>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  });
```

[image: ARRAY]

Añado el código la cuestion es que busco nuevamente y habiendo productos me marca error en la longitud de la marca error.map

adjunto código.

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cómo o cuál es la relación que existe entre las aplicaciones y el producto? Es decir ambos productos tienen el mismo conjunto de aplicaciones? También ayudaría ver tu código de React

Comment: Suponiendo que quieres pintar el nombre y una lista de a que autos aplica estimo que podrias hacer llo siguiente: tuArray.map(el => ´{<div>${el.nombre}</div><br><p>Aplicacion</p><br><ul>${el.aplicacion.map(el => ´<li>${el}</li>´).join("")}</u>´).join("")

Comment: [es.so] te da las herramientas necesarias para postear código en la pregunta, por lo tanto escribe tanto el código como los mensajes de error _como texto, con formato_, No todos pueden visualizar las imágenes, mucho menos copiar texto de ellas :)

Answer (score 0):

La solución es volver a recorrer el array, ya que dentro se encuentra el siguiente array.

```js
 const aplicaciones = productos.length > 0 && productos.map((serie) => {
    console.log('productosLENGHT', productos.length)
    return (
      <div style={{ border: '1px solid blue' }}>
        <h1>{serie.nombre} </h1>
        {serie.marca.length > 0 && serie.marca.map((season) => (
          <>
            <p>{season.nombreMarca}</p>
            <p>{season.precioVenta}</p>
          </>
        ))}
        {serie.aplicacion.length > 0 && serie.aplicacion.map((season) => (
          <ul>
            <li>{season}</li>
          </ul>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  });
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).